# How to describe the method in a React component with interface of TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a freshman with typescript. I don't understand this error in my code.
[image]

I use the `IProps` to describle the props of the class. Why does the typescript check the method of this class ? How can I solve this problem?

```
    export interface IProps extends FormComponentProps {
      dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
      loading: any;
    }

    @Form.create()
    @connect(({ global, loading }) => ({ global, loading }))
    export default class MessageBoard extends PureComponent<IProps> {
      state = {
        activated: false,
      };

      deactivate = () => {
        this.setState({ activated: true });
      };
      ...
      render() {
        ...
        return (...);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript requires that a class decorator not change the type of the class, and many React higher-order components that are often used as decorators in untyped JavaScript do not comply with this rule.  Instead of calling `connect` and `Form.create` as decorators, try calling them as functions and exporting the result:

```
class MessageBoard extends PureComponent<IProps> { ... }

export default Form.create()(
  connect(({ global, loading }) => ({ global, loading }))(
    MessageBoard));
```