# withRouter type check error as decorator of react-router

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

When I use `withRouter` as a decorator to a component, like

```
@withRouter
@observer
// observer is mobx decorator
export default class UserInfo extends React.Component<any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>1</div>
    )
  }
}
```

A type check error occurs:

```
(10,1): Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<any, string | number | symbol>, any>' is not assignable to type 'typeof UserInfo'.    Type 'Component<Pick<any, string | number | symbol>, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'UserInfo'.      Types of property 'render' are incompatible.        Type '() => ReactNode' is not assignable to type '() => Element'.
          Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
```

Why type of `<div>1</div>` is `Element`, not `ReactNode`? 
And I found the definition of render function is `render(): ReactNode`, Why typescript think it an `Element`?

And How to fix this error?

I tried to add return type of `render()`.

```
@withRouter
@observer
export default class UserInfo extends React.Component<any> {
  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <div>1</div>
    )
  }
}

// or
@observer
class UserInfo extends React.Component<any> {
  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <div>1</div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(UserInfo)
```

It works, but it's not elegance. I want to use `withRouter` as decorator. How to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to describe the method in a React component with interface of TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328375/how-to-describe-the-method-in-a-react-component-with-interface-of-typescript)

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/24077#issuecomment-429631128

Answer (score 0):

you can read the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).
In it, it says that:

> because **The class decorator is applied to the constructor of the
> class and can be used to observe, modify, or replace a class
> definition.**, that means it is different between `@withRouter ClassComponent {}` and `withRouter(ClassComponent)`