# @vx/responsive with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, responsive

I'm trying to use [@vx/responsive](https://github.com/hshoff/vx/tree/master/packages/vx-responsive) library to get with of parent component.
So, I this is some pieces of my code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react'
import { IGlobalStateable } from '../../stores/global'
const { withParentSize } = require('@vx/responsive')

interface Props extends IGlobalStateable {
  marginBottom: number,
  data: DataAnalysisType[],
}

@inject('globalState')
@withParentSize
@observer
export class SectionA extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { parentWidth, data, marginBottom, globalState } = this.props

  }
}
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Previously I used Javascript (not TypeScript) and everything worked.

Any tip is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to describe the method in a React component with interface of TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328375/how-to-describe-the-method-in-a-react-component-with-interface-of-typescript)

Comment: @MattMcCutchen thanks but I don't under stand what I have to do.. Can you explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

Call the higher-order components as functions instead of as decorators.  In your case, in order to export the wrapped class under the correct name, you'll need to define it under a different name and then store the result of calling the functions in a constant with the final name.

```
class OriginalSectionA extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { parentWidth, data, marginBottom, globalState } = this.props

  }
}

export const SectionA = inject('globalState')(withParentSize(observer(OriginalSectionA)));
```

Comment: Thanks, have you some source articles about this argument? Is this the only solution to my problem? I prefer to use a class and not a function..

Comment: Here is [the TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) for allowing class decorators to change the type of a class (specifics TBD).  I don't understand what you mean about using a class and not a function: you are using a class either way and just applying the higher-order components differently.  If the proposed solution is causing you a specific practical problem, let me know what it is.